# I try to retain the selected drop down values from the Localstorage in Angular 2

Tags: html, typescript, angular2-directives

How to bind the selected dropdown values for each dropdown after move to another page and come back to the drop down list page, the value should be retain.

I used **ngModel**, it bind one value for all  dropdowns.

But,i need like which value selected from the user that value should be retain for that particular dropdown.

I try to use **[selected]** in **Angular 2**. But, i dont know how its works. Can anyone explain that..

Comment: <select multiple materialize="material_select" [materializeSelectOptions]="selectedUsers" [(ngModel)]="selectedUsers" name="users"> 
    <option value="" disabled selected>Usuarios</option>
    <option *ngFor="let user of users" [ngValue]="users" [selected]="selectedUsers.id === user.id">{{ user.name }} ({{ user.email }}) </option>
</select>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the values from local storage by using this line `var dropLocalValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('localvaluekey'));`

Then i build some logic.

```
 var dropLocalValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('localvaluekey'));

          var tempDropAssignValues = [];

          if(dropLocalValues.length != 0)
          {
            for(var h=0;h<dropLocalValues.length;h++)
            {
              if(dropLocalValues[h].itemSeqID == this.getOneItem.seq_no)
              {
                for(var c=0;c<dropLocalValues[h].selectedAnswer.length;c++)
                {
                  tempDropAssignValues.push(dropLocalValues[h].selectedAnswer[c]);
                }
              }
            }
          }

          if(tempDropAssignValues.length != 0)
          {
            console.log(tempDropAssignValues);
            for(var d=0;d<=tempDropAssignValues.length;d++)
            {
              for(var u=0;u<this.getOneItem.item.length;u++)
              {
                if(this.getOneItem.item[u].data_format_id == 9)
                {
                  if(this.getOneItem.item[u].data_format_value[d].match_data[1].header == null || this.getOneItem.item[u].data_format_value[d].match_data[1].header == 0)
                  {
                    this.getOneItem.item[u].data_format_value[d].match_data[1].match_value = tempDropAssignValues[d-1].match_value;
                    this.getOneItem.item[u].data_format_value[d].match_data[1].seq_id = tempDropAssignValues[d-1].seq_id;
                    break;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain selected user value for your dropdown without saving to database.
Only thing you need to do is to store selected value in localStorage using

localstorage.setItem('dropdownSelectedItem','value1') on change event listener of select element.

And on page refresh you need to check if localStorage key 'dropdownSelectedItem' is selected or not.

If its set , then defaultValue parameter will be set with localstorage key value other wise you must be setting some default Value in your code for first time.

Only thing is set that defaultValue variable to localstorage value if set.